# Setting second optional parameter javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a function

```
function myfunction(a, b, c) {
  // do stuff
}
```

What is the optimal way to call this function with only param `c`?

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 'hello';
myfunction(c);
```

I was thinking this:

```
myfunction(undefined, undefined, c);
```

But there must be a better way.
I was thinking passing an object, but this function is already being used, I can't change the param structure.

Comment: write a wrapper. Also for ocd reasons, please avoid writing "most optimal".

Comment: even if no solution is supplied. ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @ASDFGerte Not just optimal. Most optimal. Optimaller. Optimallist.

Comment: Pass a default value like myfunction (a=0,b=0,c)

Comment: Don't define the method like that if most everything is optional; use an object.

Comment: You can create a new function `myfunctionc` by curry-in the function `myfunction`: `myfunctionc = c => myfunction(undefined, undefined, c); myfunctionc(c);`

Comment: That's the third parameter, btw, not the second. Because counting.

Comment: @nem035 i'd prefer `function myfunctionc(c) { return myfunction.call(this, undefined, undefined, c); }` as it is not clear whether `myfunction` requires `this`.

Comment: It seems dangerous to try to answer this question. Everything gets down-voted very quickly.

Comment: @kshetline because many of the answers are either plain wrong, did not read the question, or have bad and unnecessary side effects. I did not downvote any, but can totally see where it is coming from.

Comment: Agreed: several of the deleted answers were just plain wrong, or introduce unnecessary (and potentially als0-wrong) complications.

Comment: what is so bad to call it the standard way with `myfunction(undefined, undefined, c);`? do you need `a` and `b` as well for the function, or would you like to get a closure for this values?

Comment: for the record im not the one downvoting evreything,
also Nina its not that bad but i was thinking there must be a better way

Comment: @NinaScholz yeap, he wants to have all parameters without function modification, seems like the wrapper is only the way

Comment: the function can be modified, just not the parameter structure

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructuring like below

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 'hello'

function myfunction({a,b,c}){
  console.log(c)
}

myfunction({c})


function wrapper({params}){}
```

Another way is to create a wrapper which will control your parameters  (without function modification)

```js
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 'hello'

function myfunction(a,b,c){
  console.log(c)
}

function wrapperForMyFunction({a, b, c}){
  return myfunction(a,b,c)
}

wrapperForMyFunction({ c })
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I believe it's because the OP explicitly mentioned that he/she cannot modify the original function >  "*I was thinking passing an object, but this function is already being used, I can't change the param structure.*"

Comment: *shrug* I wouldn't have downvoted; I think it's a better approach than anything other than a wrapper. (I think a wrapper is best because it preserves the original method's intent, but if I'm in control of the original method, and there's a bunch of stuff that can be option, to me an object makes more sense.)

Answer (score 2):

The best method is to define the parameters in the right order, so the last ones are the optionals, and then you will be able to use the optional arguments as defined in ES6

```
function(c, a=1, b=2) {
   // ...
}
```

Since named parameters are not supported in JS, if you have many optional parameters, replace them by a single object.

```
function(obj) {
   // obj.a, obj.b, obj.c
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `arguments` object in the function body.

```
function() {
    // arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]
}
```

If you are not able to redesign the function, then find out the default values for the parameters, and use those. It is usually `0`, an empty array or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (use bind):

```js
a = 1; b = 2; c = 'hello'


function myfunction(a,b,c){
  console.log('a = ', a, 'b = ', b, 'c = ', c);
}

// newFunc same myfunction but first and second parameter is undefined
// potentially incorrect if 'this' is necessary
const newFunc = myfunction.bind(null, undefined, undefined);

newFunc(c);

newFunc(c, 'something');
```

Comment: Seems overkill (and potentially incorrect if `this` is necessary) when you can just create a wrapper.

Comment: I change it to null, but I don't sure that .
Can you tell me that is right or wrong ?

Comment: It's not "right" or "wrong", I just don't see `bind` as being the optimal solution--it's just a wrapper function. I didn't downvote, I just wouldn't do it this way--it's a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = "hello";

myfunction({c:c})

function myfunction(a,b,c){
  if (typeof a === "object") {
      obj = a;
      a = obj.a;
      b = obj.b;
      c = obj.c;
  }
 
  // do stuff
}
```

this will work but "a" can never be a object, its the only issue

Answer (score -1):

i think you are looking for var args. please take a look.

```
var a = 1; b = 2; c = 'hello'
function varargsFunction1()  
{  
    console.log(arguments[2]);
}    
varargsFunction1(a,b,c);
```

Comment: Certainly valid, but relying on position is fraught with danger.