# vuejs pass extra parameter to function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

Is it possible within Quasar Form rules to pass extra parameter?
This had to do with the following template code:

```
<q-field outlined v-else-if="prop.component === 'checkbox'" 
  class="q-gutter-sm" 
  v-model="dataRef[key]"
  :label="prop.label"
  :rules="[isCheckLimit]"
  >
    <q-option-group
    style="margin-top:20px;"
      :options="prop.options"
      type="checkbox"
      v-model="dataRef[key]"
    />

</q-field>
```

The function:

```
  const isCheckLimit = (v) => {
    return v.length > 2 || t('checked-to-much')
  }
```

I want that number 2 to be dynamic instead of static, is it possible to pass for example a number to that function? I cant find any clear information about that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting second optional parameter javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267279/setting-second-optional-parameter-javascript)

Comment: `const isCheckLimit = (v, vLength = 2) => {
return v.length > vLength || t('checked-to-much')
}`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I already tried that, but that doesnt work. As soon as I use this rule: isCheckLimit(4) or isCheckLimit(v,4)  it doesnt even call the function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your rule as function in your rules array, first lets update your validation function to accept second argument, I will also set it to default value of 2:

```
    const isCheckLimit = (v, minLength = 2) => {
      return v.length > minLength || t('checked-to-much');
    };
```

Now if you use this for your rules:

```
  :rules="[(value) => isCheckLimit(value, 4)]"
```

Your validation function will use `4` for `minLength` instead of default `2`.

Original way will also work:

```
  :rules="[isCheckLimit]"
```

But will use the default value of `2` for `minLength`